# Al compilar la aplicacion, no detecta todos los cambios que estan en modo desarrollo. React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, reactjs

Lo que sucede es que al momento de compilar la aplicación con `react-native`, utilizando los comandos:

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

generando una .APK, ese no funciona correctamene, no detecta algunos cambios como, peticiones a la `API`, cambios a `Firebase`.

***En modo desarrollo si funciona!.**

Comment: Por favor lee: [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Dudo que con la información que has suministrado la comunidad pueda ayudarte, pero, si requieres ayuda, debes leer **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y [edit] la pregunta proporcionando lo que aprendiste al leer **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me pasaba esto mismo en `Apache Cordova` lo que pasaba era que a la hora de crear el `release` quedaban estructuras viejas.

> - Eliminar los archivos de la carpeta `/release` estos se crean al compilar nuevamente.
> - haz lo mismo para `/debug` y vuelves a compilar nuevamente en "modo debug".

así logré solucionar mi problema.

espero haberte ayudado